# Auth scaffolding doesn't work in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In Laravel, I had made authentication scaffolding every time the authentication is requested for every action I can't debug.

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'),function(){ 
    //module routes
    Route::resource('menu','MenuController');
    Route::resource('banner','BannerController');
    Route::resource('products','ProductsController');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('Dashboard');
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
Auth::routes();
```

Comment: It should be like this: Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {...

Comment: the authentication scaffolding works correctly but the session doesn't persists continuously...

Comment: To make session persistent, also use 'web' middleware. like this; Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'web']], function () {...